# Prove $(S^{-1}(I/J))^2 = S^{-1}((I^2+J)/J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring, $J\subset I\subset A$ be two ideals, let $S$ be a multiplicative set prove that :

$$(S^{-1}(I/J))^2 = S^{-1}((I^2+J)/J)$$

---

My attempt , I try to use the explicit expression for the localization, and figure out as set they are the same, but it seems not very good. Or maybe we can use the exact sequence , but don't know which exact sequence to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first show that $(S^{-1}(I/J))^2\subset  S^{-1}((I^2+J)/J)$. Suppose $xy/st\in (S^{-1}(I/J))^2$, where $x, y \in I, s,t \in S$. Then $st \in S, xy \in I^2$ so that certainly $xy/st\in S^{-1}((I^2+J)/J)$. Since every element in $(S^{-1}(I/J))^2$ is finite sum of such $xy/st$, we get the desired inclusion. On the other hand, if $xy/s\in S^{-1}((I^2+J)/J)$ where $x, y \in I, s \in S$, then $x/1, y/s \in S^{-1}(I/J)$ which shows $xy/s\in (S^{-1}(I/J))^2$. An argument similar to before leads to $S^{-1}((I^2+J)/J)\subset (S^{-1}(I/J))^2$.

Comment: Tip: you can simplify the notation a lot, which may be perplexing you. Let $f$ be the composition of the canonical maps $A \to S^{-1}A \to S^{-1}A/S^{-1}AJ=B $ (or $A \to A/J \to S^{-1}(A/J)$, the same thing). Then the equation is just $(Bf(I))^2=B(f(I))^2$. This holds for general ring homomorphisms.

Comment: The comment looks much clearer, thank you.